# Hibernate custom query for search screen

Tags: java, hibernate

I have search screen which has 10 fields and involves around 5 to 6 tables to get the result. I am writing a custom SQL query and appending where condition only when a value exists.

Can someone please suggest is this the right approach or any other better way.

I cannot use any plugins or additional APIs for my situation.

```
StringBuffer sqlQuery = new StringBuffer();
sqlQuery.append (" select member.* from member, customer, case where customer.status='A');
if(firstName != null)
sqlQuery.append("customer.firstName= :firstName");

if(caseid != null)
sqlQuery.append("case.caseid =:caseid");

SQLQuery queryObj = createSQLquery(sqlQuery.toString());
queryObj.list();
```

where as **member, customer, case** are actual tables.

**UPDATE**

when I am adding where condition to string buffer

```
if(caseid != null)
sqlQuery.append(" and case.caseid =:caseid");

and when queryObj is formed I am doing it as
if(caseid != null)
queryObj.setString("caseid", caseid);

is there better way to add after queryObj (to combine both)?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not necessarily the right approach. SQL is not the query language of choice when using Hibernate. HQL should be preferred when possible. And Hibernate also has [the Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria) which has been designed precisely to build dynamic queries.

Comment: using Criteria as I told I have more than 5 tables I don't know how to refer in each other. And if I refer, some of them are one to many, many to one, many to many. I am kind of using HQL, edited the question again, please check and let me know. Thanks

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations. I can't do more than linking to the documentation. Try to read it, understand it, and experiment. You won't be able to be a criteria wizard in 3 minutes time. If you're stuck, post a question explaining precisely what you're trying to do, and join the relevant code and mapping of the entities involved.

Comment: can you please see the update once and help me with that little bit more?